# Permissions on Maven downloaded dependencies change and don't inherit from parent folder

Tags: windows, maven, artifactory

Hi Stackoverflow community. My first post here... I am working on a project that automates code analysis by injecting it into Jenkins build pipelines. Analysis requires inclusion of JAR libraries which we download from Artifactory based on Maven pom.xml project configurations. To do that we issue Maven command in the following fashion :

mvn -f pom.xml dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=c:\temp

Everything is working just fine, but for some projects, occasionally, the file level security is somehow changed so that the Jenkins service account user no longer has access to those files. The files looses permissions inheritance from the parent folders and somehow acquire permissions that no longer allow the user to access the JAR file.

I am not sure whether the issue is related to Maven or to the way Windows 2016 boxes are setup, but the issue seems to happens only on specific JARs and even specific versions of JAR files. Most files are download and accessible just fine, but a handful of files are consistently having this issue. I tried to look into whether those permissions can be somehow controlled by Maven configurations, but did not find anything relevant. I also looked into permission setting in Artifactory, but once again did not see anything that could be impacting it. Any direction or suggestions on what path to take to investigate would be appreciated. Thank you!

Update: It looks like the permissions for some of the JAR files are taken from the local maven repository located under c:\users\xxx\.m2\repository folder. When I check the permissions of the destination folder they are exactly the same as they are in the source. It happens for some JARs, but others take on inherited permissions of the destination folder.

Comment: Just use a usual build in Jenkins `mvn clean package` that will download everything is needed ....What kind of analysis ?

Comment: @khmarbaise downloading of the JAR dependencies is not a problem. That is working just fine. The issue is that the downloaded JARs are assigned permissions different from those of the containing folder. I have no idea why that is happening and trying to figure out what is overriding those permissions instead of inheriting them from the parent folder.

Comment: The Artifactory permissions settings does not have any effect on the permissions of the downloaded files. Artifactory has no control over how the downloaded files are being saved

Comment: Thanks @DrorBereznitsky. That was my expectation as well, but started to think there is something going on when file permission started changing. Thanks for the confirmation.